# Remove entries from Connect to Server dialog

Tags: sql-server-2005

In SSMSE 2005, once you successfully connect to a SQL Server instance, that server appears in the drop down box in the Connect To Server dialog box.

Does anyone know how to *remove* an entry from this list?

I haven't found anything in the registry or in any local files.

Answer (score 1):

On Vista delete:

```
C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\90\Tools\Shell\mru.dat
```

On XP delete:

```
C:\Documents and Settings\<user>\Application Data\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\90\Tools\Shell\mru.dat
```

Unfortunately this removes all entries. I haven't found a way to remove a single entry yet.

If the above doesn't work I have heard mention of:

```
C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\90\Tools\ShellSEM\mru.dat
```

or

```
C:\Documents and Settings\<user>\Application Data\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\90\Tools\ShellSEM\mru.dat
```

but cannot test as I do not have the folder.

An article on the SQL Server 2005 Management and Administration Tools:

http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=680822&seqNum=2

Comment: No joy. I don't have that file, and yes I checked for hidden files. RegSrvr.xml looked promising, but it's entries don't match what's in the dialog. There's an MRU.dat in Tools\ShellSEM but deleting it had no effect, and the file was created on restarting SSMSE.

Comment: mmmhhh I heard about this before...I'll see if I can find the article.

Answer (score 1):

For Windows 7:

For SqlExpress 2008 front-end using a SQL Server 2005 back-end delete the following file:

```
C:\Users\"user"\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Shell\SqlStudio.bin
```

This file will get recreated once you restart SQL Server